# Set Existing IP address to New Azure VM Machine

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-vm

In our organization, currently we have our Windows SQL server machine in on premise. And we are planning to move that to Azure VM. And now my question is, while creating the new Azure VM is it possible to set the IP address that what we have for our current on premise machine. So that after the migration, we don't need to do any config connection settings changes.

Comment: Not easily. If you put another Windows machine at the original IP address you could try setting up a proxy to the Azure VM's public IP with `netsh interface portproxy ...` but I wouldn't consider it production quality. This sort of question probably belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is the Ip address static and public?

Answer (score 0):

Bring-your-own-IP is currently not available on Azure. There is an open Feedback item (which says it is Planned). https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/4127175-bring-your-own-public-ip-address-space-and-interne